# Scrollanimation IOS => SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list

Tags: javascript

I get an error with my scroll animation in older IOS devices (2019 and older):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.

```
class EventEmitter {
  listeners = {}
  addListener(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    this.listeners[eventName].push(fn);
    return this;
  }
```

How would I have to write `listeners = {}` so that the error doesn't show up?

Answer (score 1):

[Public class fields at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) become properly supported in Safari 14.1. That is linked to iOS 14 which supports all the way back to the iPhone 6s which was released in 2015.

If you have a pre-2019 device which is newer than that then it just needs an OS update.

---

To support browsers which haven't implemented public class fields either:

- Assign their value in the constructor function (quick, simple, doesn't work the same way for inheritance)
- Assign `EventEmitter.prototype.listeners` after creating the class.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me how to do this? I unfortunately can not javascript :(

Comment: listeners (){}; was working, But, unfortunately, there are other errors. Too bad. Must do a fallback. Thank you very much.